# How can I append to to an existing Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python

This is what I have so far to retrieve data from polygon.io. For each sym I would like to add it to df

```
sym = ['OCGN', 'TKAT', 'MMAT', 'MDIA', 'PHUN']
df = pd.DataFrame()
i=0
for i in range(len(sym)):
    stock = sym[i]
    url = f'https://api.polygon.io/v2/aggs/ticker/{stock}/range/1/day/{fromdate}/{to}? 
    adjusted=true&sort=asc&limit=50000&apiKey=Demo'.format()
    tick = requests.get(url)
    tick =pd.json_normalize(tick.json()["results"])
    daa = (tick.iloc[[-1]])
    data = pd.DataFrame(daa)
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
print(df)

output
v      vw     o     c     h      l              t       
0  15426806.0  6.2736  6.31  6.03  6.66  6.030  1638334800000   
1    464144.0  4.9949  5.16  4.73  5.28  4.640  1638334800000
2   8101699.0  3.5164  3.75  3.36  3.82  3.300  1638334800000
3    109407.0  5.0286  4.90  4.77  5.28  4.654  1638334800000
4  45679175.0  3.7679  3.01  3.25  3.26  2.780  1638334800000
```

Comment: what is the real question?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Add each symbol to your dataframe?  Put `data['sym'] = sym[i]` as the second to last line in your loop.  Also consider concatenating a list of dataframes instead of appending, it is more computationally efficient per the Pandas docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: OMG it finally worked when I did data['sym'] = sym[i] as it was suggested. Thank you for very much